# Flutter - how to wrap contents the row width in the ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I want to draw a vertical list.
Each item in list should be filled only wrapped size.

But my code draw the list items with full width like:

[image]

I tried to use `MainAxisSize.min` but it doesn't work.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  HomePage({super.key});

  final List<String> list = ["apple", "banana", "cat", "dragon"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text('[$index]'),
                  const SizedBox(width: 4),
                  Text(list[index])
                ],
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you use `ListView`, the child will will fill the width.

if you want to show not much data, consider use `SingleChildScrollView`
i wrote an article here to compare them and explain when to use it

https://medium.com/easyread/my-october-flutter-notes-2-6e0c78cf2e56

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add `Align` and align left:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Text('[$index]'),
                    const SizedBox(width: 4),
                    Text(list[index])
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `ListView` take all avaialble width, even if you wrap your `container` with `Align`, this just change the `item's width` not the width that `ListView` takes(if you wrap your listview with colored container you will see that).

If you are not using long list, You can use `SingleChildScrollView` and `Column` like this:

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: list.mapIndexed((index, e) {
            return Container(
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text('[$index]'),
                  const SizedBox(width: 4),
                  Text(e)
                ],
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

More of a workaround: depending on the layout seeked, either place the ListView into a Row or put another widget at the end of the row.